# Is a hard to turn shaft a sign of a bad DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a 220V ungeared DC motor and the shaft is very hard to spin when not powered and the two leads are not connected to each other. I have to use pliers to get it to spin. It feels consistently lumpy. I am getting a resistance reading of about 34.5 ohms from the two leads.

I have another 90V motor and although there is some resistance when turning the shaft, it can be turned by hand.  Does this indicate something wrong with the  motor?

[image: Photo of Motor with resistance reading]

**NOTES**
I disassembled it and put it back together. I was shocked to find the rotor wasn't centered within the housing causing it to stick to the field's strong magnet.  Apparently, there was an extra lock ring on one of the long housing screws causing it to cock towards one side of the stator. I hand to position the end mill precisely using light hammer taps to the end bells.  While holding it in position and checking the rotation, I tightened the long housing screws in an alternating fashion until both were tight.

Comment: Is the motor shorted or connected to some electrical load?

Comment: Thanks.  But no, the motor not connected, neither are the two leads.

Comment: Was it easy to turn before?\

Comment: Yes. I'd dismantle it (if I wanted to fix it), check the bearings on both ends, look for anything that might have gotten inside, and check for interior damage (dings, etc.) Mostly, I'd expect a bearing problem (no longer perpendicular to the shaft, bent, damaged or ground balls, etc.) and would be wondering where I'd get new ones.

Comment: Ground rotor laminate insulation may increase pole tip temperature from eddy current losses. Keep a pulse on motor temperature under load.

Comment: It's fixed for now.  Every motor I've dismantled had gooves and or bosses to keep the rotor, field and housing concentric to each other. This one had no such design, which was odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of the motor.  However, if the motor is small enough that you can put pliers on the shaft and turn it that way, then there is probably something wrong with the motor.  One or more bearings could be damaged, for example.

Comment: Man... You sure know your stuff!  See mu revison.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a burned up motor can bind inside (windings scraping), especially if it is made to very tight tolerances.

You might want to pull the brushes out and have a look at them.

A motor without a gearbox should not show much resistance to turning.